# Prove that in the quotient group $G/N$, $(gN)^\alpha=g^\alpha N$ for all integers $\alpha$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification

I wanted to verify my proof's logic, because this question seems awfully trivial, but every time when I feel this way, most likely I am wrong on multiple levels and not understanding things correctly.

By definition of quotient group given in Dummit and Foote, $G/N$ is a quotient group if $N$ is the kernel of some homomorphism between $G$ and some group $H$ and all elements in $G/N$ are left cosets of $N$. Then we know that a subgroup is normal if and only if it is a kernel of some homomorphism, hence we know that $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$. Now, since $N$ is normal then the product of cosets are well defined as $$(uN)(vN)=uvN$$ then of course we have for any positive powers $g^\alpha N=(gN)^\alpha$. For negative powers, $-\alpha$ is positive, we can play around with some equality to prove this case.

Does this logic work? Thanks!